# Extracting z values from hurdle model output, 'pscl' package in R

Tags: r, pscl

I am using the `hurdle()` function from the `pscl` package to run negative binomial hurdle models in R.

I would like to extract only the list of z values from the model output and assign those values to a vector. But I cannot figure out how to do this?

Here is the basic outline of my model:

```
real.mod <- summary(hurdle(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4  |  x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data=mydata, dist = "negbin", zero.dist = "negbin", link = "logit"))

real.mod
```

For example, I have tried:

`coef(summary(real.mod))[,3]`

But this doesn't work.

Any guidance on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(pscl)
#> Classes and Methods for R developed in the
#> Political Science Computational Laboratory
#> Department of Political Science
#> Stanford University
#> Simon Jackman
#> hurdle and zeroinfl functions by Achim Zeileis
data("bioChemists", package = "pscl")

fm_hp1 <- hurdle(art ~ ., data = bioChemists)
z <- fm_hp1$coefficients$zero
z
#> (Intercept)    femWomen  marMarried        kid5         phd        ment 
#>  0.23679601 -0.25115113  0.32623358 -0.28524872  0.02221940  0.08012135
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Dave, wonderful - thank you! I see now I can extract just the z values using ```real.mod$coefficients$zero[,3]``` and 
```real.mod$coefficients$count[,3]```